# High Google Firebase Storage Cost for saving and downloading .mp4 files?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-storage

I'm saving videos to Firebase Storage and creating a URL for it which I saving into Cloud Firestore. So when ever someone watch a video I call the URL and  Firebase downloads it. That increased my project costs enormously.
The question that I have is, is there a way to save the mp4 files cheaper?
And maybe also make it faster to download?
The best solution will be if I can like I used before. So in the new solution, also use the download URL which I saved in cloud Firestore. So that I don't need change too much. My Project is using Flutter in client side.

I created a mobile app, where user can upload videos for example like Instagram or TikTok.

I'm willing to pay if you freelancer and can help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use Youtube or Vimeo to store your videos for free (Vimeo is limited to 500mb).
Then you can use a package from pub.dev to display these videos.

[YouTube package](https://pub.dev/packages/youtube_player_flutter) (does not support to download the file, only playback)

[Vimeo package](https://pub.dev/packages/vimeoplayer) (max 500mb, then you have to pay)

So both have their advantages and disadvantages.

Comment: Thanks for answering. But I created a mobile app, where user can upload videos for example like instagram. So your solution will probably not work.

Comment: Then you may try to compress the video file or enforce a lower resolution. I believe [this package](https://pub.dev/packages/image_picker) can do that for you on the device itself before it's uploaded to firebase, so you don't need to write a cloud function

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to upload videos to YouTube using Google API. There is an example done using flutter which can be ideal for your use-case. Have a look at this video on [youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2Kdlnn-MN9c).